Click on a certain type of file to render react custom components instead of using webview. How to achieve this?
1、click like .test file
2、not use webview API
3、render react CustomEditor
"customEditors": [
      {
        "viewType": "my-custom-editor-component",
        "displayName": "my-custom-editor-component",
        "selector": [
          {
            "filenamePattern": "*.test"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

in node.js file use vscode.open，but not woking.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
